# Android: Create new object and manipulate/call new methods serially with Synchronized

Tags: java, android, multithreading, oop

I am attempting to have a user create a new *Flow* object and add it to an ArrayList to keep track when they press then `"+"` on the tool bar.

I am struggling with the multithreading of Java, because my methods that require the object and its properties, are running before the object is instantiated caused all sorts of problems

I want my methods to execute serially (ie. show dialog, get name, use object constructor, add new object to list) which is why I've attempted to use the `Synchronized` action on an object which I declared but did not instantiate.

This strategy can't seem to work because the object locked onto cannot be null.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null reference used for synchronization (monitor-enter)
```

Any thoughts on how I could make my methods run in serial like this pseudo code:

```
private Flow newFlow; //Blank flow object declared.
private static List<Flow> flowsInStream = new ArrayList<Flow>();

synchronized (newFlow) {
  flowDialog(); 
     // presents user a dialog box to receive input. 
     // takes user input, invokes separate method to actually instantiate 
     // the newFlow object using the user input. 
     // Originally blank newFlow object now has: 
        // newFlow.name = userInput
     // --X END X--
  addToStream(newFlow);
     // adds the newly instantiated newFlow object to the flowsInStream
     // array to keep track of them. 
     // --X END X-- 
  executedCorrectly(); 
     // displays log message showing both the newFlow.name & the current 
     // elements in the flowsInStream array. 
     // --X END X-- 
 } // end of synchronized
```

TheStream.java

```
public class TheStream extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = TheStream.class.getName();
    private Toolbar streamToolbar;
    private Flow theFlow; //Blank flow object declared.

    private static List<Flow> flowsInStream = new ArrayList<Flow>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_stream);

        streamToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.streamToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(streamToolbar);
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_thestream, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
                return true;

            case R.id.action_newFlow:

                    flowDialog();
                    addToStream(theFlow);
                    executedCorrectly();

                return true;

            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

    public void flowDialog() {
        //Creates dialog box asking for name for the new flow
        AlertDialog.Builder newFlowDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TheStream.this);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.setMarginStart(70);
        params.setMarginEnd(150);

        //Create edit text field for name entry
        final EditText nameInputET = new EditText(TheStream.this);

        //Sets maximum length of the EditText
        nameInputET.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(30)});

        //Adds the ET and params to the layout of the dialog box
        layout.addView(nameInputET, params);

        newFlowDialog.setTitle("Name your new Flow.");
        newFlowDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.new_flow);

        newFlowDialog.setView(layout);


        newFlowDialog.setPositiveButton("Lets Roll",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        if (nameInputET.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                            Toast.makeText(TheStream.this, "Every Flow deserves a good name :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            flowDialog(); //Recall the dialog

                        } else {
                            // Sets name of flow object
                            theFlow = instantiateFlow(nameInputET.getText().toString());
                        }
                    }
                });

        newFlowDialog.setNegativeButton("Nevermind",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        //Display Alert
        newFlowDialog.show();

    }

    protected Flow instantiateFlow(String userInput) {
        //Instantiates (Constructor) the newFlow object.

        Flow newFlow = new Flow(userInput);
        Log.d(TAG, "Your flow's name is " + newFlow.getFlowName());
         /** Returns errors attached below */
        return newFlow;
    }

    public void addToStream(Flow flow) {
        flowsInStream.add(flow);
    }

    public void executedCorrectly() {
        Log.d(TAG, "The synchronized activity executed correctly because the new Flow object's name is " + theFlow.getFlowName());
        Log.d(TAG, "The new Flow list is also updated check it out: " + flowsInStream);
    }
}
```

Flow.java

```
public class Flow {

    private String flowName;

    public Flow() {

    } // End of default constructor

    public Flow(String flowName) {
        this.flowName = flowName;
    } // End of constructor

    /** Getters & Setters **/
    public void setFlowName(String flowName) {
        this.flowName = flowName;
    }
    public String getFlowName() {
        return this.flowName;
    }
```

If any additional code would help, just let me know and I'd be happy to post some. And if possible in your answer please mention where my technical understanding was lacking in attempting this.

ERROR RECEIVED:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'java.lang.String nhacks16.flow.Main.Flow.getFlowName()' on a null object 
reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy are using `synchronized (newFlow)`, when `newFlow` is still `null`. You can't use `synchronized` on a `null` reference. If you really want to synchronize, create a different `Object` (any `Object` will do) and synchronize on that one, or synchronize on `this` (just using `synchronized {` without parenthesis). Which one is correct, depends on what kind of parallelism you want to guard against, which brings me to the next point:

I don't see any multithreading, so I'm not sure, if you even need synchronization.

Comment: Hi mastov, thanks for the reply. How do I make the methods run in serial if I don't use synchronize? I want my second method (addToStream) to wait until the first method (flowDialog) has completed, before executing.

Comment: @RobertSimoes: If you don't use multithreading, they will execute "serially" without the need to do anything. What makes you think that there is multithreading going on?

Comment: Originally I did just put the methods one after another without a synchronized block and I would get the log messages: 

 " The synchronized activity executed correctly because the new Flow object's name is **null** "

which I thought meant that the Log message grabbed the newFlow.name before the object was instantiated with flowDialog().

Comment: @RobertSimoes: I don't think that's related to multithreading. But in order for us to be able to figure out, why that happened, please post the relevant code.

Comment: Apologizes, I've attached the entire code (unedited), I was incorrect the error received was a nullPointerException, which has been shown below!

Comment: @RobertSimoes: From what I see, the only way for `theFlow` to be `null` is, that the "negative button" was clicked. In that case `theFlow` is never initialized, but the method `executedCorrectly` is executed anyway, thus accessing a `null` object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111028/discussion-between-robert-simoes-and-mastov).

Answer (score 1):

@mastov was completely correct in that there doesn't appear to be any multi threading in the code and my newFlow object was `null`. But I just wanted to clarify what my own technical mistake was after reading his comments and a friend of mine pointed it out, in case someone else finds useful!

I was under the impression that that the dialog box FREEZES all activity (ie. the methods: `addToStream(theFlow);` and `executedCorrectly();`will wait until `flowDialog()`finished before executing themselves).

Thus, because the methods seemed to execute before the dialog was gone, I was under the impression that they were running on different threads.

The reason for the nullPointerException was that the object **was not** instantiated until user clicked on the button and input text. So once the flowDialog was set up, the next method would run, but because the flow object **was not** instantiated it threw the null exception!

Comment: +1 Thanks, I fell for the same thing when analyzing your code! The non-blocking call to `Dialog.show()` is a bit counter-intuitive, IMHO.